# To restore my newborn photoes: How to root LG G3 D852 (Canadian variant)?

Tags: root-access, lg-g3

I connected my LG D852 with MM to the LG software, I had a pop-up that there is an upgrade so clicked OK thinking that the data will not be wiped as long as I will be still on MM. That was wrong! ALL data are wiped including my newborn first photos which are priceless to me. I tried some apps like diskdigger and some software on the PC but all of them require root to perform. I tried all rooting methods that I am aware of, but nothing is working. I can't downgrade to LP since writing on the internal memory is not a wise move to restore my data. Any ideas how to root that without having to downgrade?

Comment: When rooting, you normally have to wipe all data again, so I think any data rescue program will be unsuccessful here.

Comment: @timoschwarzer that is not entirely true. (1) Apps like kingoroot can root most devices without wiping all data. (2) Wiping data doesn't mean it is gone or overwritten and that is exactly how recovery programs work.